# SQLALCHEMY Connection busy with other hstmt results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a multi-threaded program with Sqlalchemy. I use the scopped_session object globally by instantiating it in each queries, but sometimes I get the error that the connection is busy with another process. Before executing my queries, I thought about throwing them into a queue object, but I don't know exactly where I went wrong.

```
def create_scoped_session(engine):
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
    conn = engine.connect()
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=conn))
    return Session

session = create_scoped_session(engin)
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager #Session Manager
def ManagedSession(session):
    if session is None:
        raise ValueError("..")
    try:
        yield session
        session.expunge_all()
        session.commit()
        session.flush()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.remove()

def add(entity):#I run my queries like that
    with ManagedSession(session) as session: 
        count = session.query(self.modelorm).filter_by(**kwargs).count()
```

I have a service running every x seconds and asynchronous operations that are querying the database with events and the program repeatedly throws me this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Connection busy with other hstmt results (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

how should i run my queries when working with multiple threads

Comment: Do I need to create a different connection for each thread?